# How to change or add openssl 32 bit driver on Centos 6.4

Tags: openssl, 32-bit, centos6

I have no idea how to do this but I need to get 32 bit openssl to work in order to install another application.

this is my version info: (result of openssl version -a)

OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
built on: Wed Feb 13 11:31:32 EST 2013
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  rsax dynamic

I don't even know where to start (other than google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Architect at my work figured it out, I don't have exact steps but this is what i got:

```
yum install glibc.i686
yum install libstdc++.i686
yum install openssl.i686
```

there was something also about sym-links but i don't know from where to where.  essentially we  needed to install the 32-bit drivers (the openssl.i686) and some dependencies (the other stuff)

hope this can help someone.